# How to navigate between monitors using the mouse in a circular way?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, mouse

I have three screens, 1, 2, 3.

When I use the mouse and am on the most left screen 1 and want to get to screen 3, I have to move all the way right through to screen 2 in order to get to screen 3.

I rather just move my mouse to the left border so that it comes out directly at the right border of screen 3. Currently, those outer borders stop mouse movement altogether.

So instead of my monitors to form a plane, I want them to connect like the surface of a cylinder.

Is there a way to achieve this using gnome-shell?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Amazing how the phrasing of a question can hinder finding the solution. It sure seems like a duplicate.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't mind to "waste" the 50 points; I got two upvotes due to the bounty and I I think it would be unfair to Gsxr1k who provided a seemingly valid answer (haven't tested yet). Also, the bounty made us realize that this was a duplicate to begin with, so worth it.